# Spark SQL - Alias a column with comma in column name

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have to store data from a temp view in databricks using spark SQL to a dataframe in comma seperated format. 
So, for multiple columns in the temp view, dataframe needs to store only one column with all the data column seperated

Below is the example:

```
Temp View: temp_class
roll  name   subject
111   Ram    Maths

Dataframe: df

roll,name,subject
111,Ram,Maths

Below is the code without alias:

df= spark.sql("""
select concat(roll,',',name,',',subject) from temp_class
"""
)
```

When I try to add alias like the conventional SQL way (code below), databricks throws an error - Mismatched input "roll,name,subject" expecting

```
df= spark.sql("""
select concat(roll,',',name,',',subject) as "roll,name,subject" from temp_class
"""
)
```

How can I put in the alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put column alias name within `` (grave accent or backtick).

try this, It should work for you -

```
df= spark.sql("""
select concat(roll,',',name,',',subject) as `roll,name,subject` from temp_class
"""
)
```